# How to fit content of minipage dynamically within a standalone?

Tags: minipage, scaling, standalone

I'm trying to create a standalone but the content won't fit inside.

[image]

I think `\minipage{\textwidth}` causes the issue. I know I can set e.g. `\minipage{21cm}` but I want to keep this dynamic since the table is created automatically from an [R script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55611598/6574038). I also tried `\minipage{\linewidth}` but that didn't solve the problem either.

I have to adjust the script anyway to add the addition to `\begin{tabular}` and the additional `\toprule` which is not yet created automatically. It's quite a construction site right now. Therefore I also would appreciate if there would be a solution that doesn't change the code too much.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,array}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\begin{document}
\minipage{\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}>{\hangindent=1.5em\hangafter=1}p{2in}rrrrrrr}
\toprule
{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Treatment A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Treatment B}  & {}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
\cmidrule{5-7}
 & Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit & amets & consetetur & sadipscing \\
  \hline
luptatum blandit invidunt takimata & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  sanctus eirmod sea labore & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  erats sea eirmod blandit & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  sea iriure illum eum & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  zzril consetetur ipsum takimata & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  dolore hendrerit justo sit & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  sit augue et Lorem & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  labore amets et dolores & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  ipsum justo autem vel & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  aliquyam velit luptatum Lorem & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}

\captionof{table}{My caption}
\endminipage
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated in this case but `\minipage` `\endminipage` should be `\begin{minipage}` `\end{minipage}` the implementation assumes the group from the environment is there.

Comment: You might also be interested in the varwidth package/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs,array}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\begin{document}

\sbox0{%
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{4pt}}>{\hangindent=1.5em\hangafter=1}p{2in}rrrrrrr}
\toprule
{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Treatment A} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Treatment B}  & {}\\
\cmidrule{2-4}
\cmidrule{5-7}
 & Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit & amets & consetetur & sadipscing \\
  \hline
luptatum blandit invidunt takimata & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  sanctus eirmod sea labore & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  erats sea eirmod blandit & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  sea iriure illum eum & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  zzril consetetur ipsum takimata & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  dolore hendrerit justo sit & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  sit augue et Lorem & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  labore amets et dolores & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  ipsum justo autem vel & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
  aliquyam velit luptatum Lorem & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 & 9.99 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}}

\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
\usebox0

\captionof{table}{My caption}
\end{minipage}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice and clean, thanks. The actual output will then look better than on the image.

Comment: The line at the upper edge of the page, how could we omit this?